# Extracting Directory from Path with Ending Slash

Tags: python

What is an elegant way of extracting a directory from a path with an ending slash?

For example

`/foo/bar/test/`

and I want `test`.

I can do `os.path.basename` if there was no ending `/`.

Is my next best option to do something like:

```
  if directory[:-1] == '/':
    basename = os.path.basename(directory[:-1])
  else:
    basename = os.path.basename(directory)
```

as this is probably not os agnostic or very clean.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calling `os.path.abspath` will take care of that for you:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.abspath('/foo/bar/test/')
'/foo/bar/test'
>>> os.path.abspath('/foo/bar/test')
'/foo/bar/test'
>>>
```

So:

```
>>> os.path.basename(os.path.abspath('/foo/bar/test/'))
'test'
```

Comment: Well, it looks like Steven submitted the same answer about the same time I did.

Comment: Good guy @StevenRumbalski